# Getting JSON data with PHP

Tags: php

Apologies if this has been asked a thousand times, but I can't find a good tutorial on how to do this correctly and searching on Stack is coming up trumps.

I have a JSON file which has data like this:

```
   {
      "store":"Store 1",
      "cat":"Categories",
      "general_cat":"Categories",
      "spec_cat":"Accessories"
   },
   {
      "store":"Store 1",
      "cat":"Categories",
      "general_cat":"Categories",
      "spec_cat":"Accessories"
   },
```

with about 50 entries in it. I'm trying to parse this data and store the values in variables.

So far I've tried:

```
$string     = file_get_contents("jsonFile.json");
$json_array = json_decode($string,true);

foreach ($json_array as $key => $value){

    $store = $key -> store;
    $general_cat = $key -> general_cat;
    $spec_cat = $key -> spec_cat;

    if (!is_null($key -> mainImg_select)){
        $cat = $key -> cat;
    }

    echo $headURL;
}
```

This is resulting in "Trying to get property of non object" errors. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First, your json code is not semantically correct. A list of object should be between `[` and `]` like `[{...},{...}]`. Secondly, you are using the value `true` for the second parameter of `json_decode`. If it is set to true, you will not manipulate object, but associative arrays. So, `$key->store` will not be available. At the same time it may be instead `$value["store"]`.

Comment: The JSON is between square brackets, I was just showing how the data is stored. I've tried setting json_decode's second value to false but this still gives me non-object errors.

Comment: That's because you have to use `$value` and not `$key`. Please read completely my answer. After `json_decode`, `$json_array` is an array of associative arrays. So, `$key` is a numeric index, and `$value` the array you wat to manipulate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second argument of `json_decode` tells the function whether to return the data as an object, or an array.

Object access uses the `->` symbol. To return an object from `json_decode` either use `json_decode($jsonString)` or `json_decode($jsonString, false)` (the second argument is [false by default](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php))

```
$jsonString = '{ "this_is_json" : "hello!" }';

$obj = json_decode($jsonString);

echo $obj->this_is_json // "hello!";
```

You can also access your json data as an array by setting the second argument to `true`

```
$jsonString = '{ "this_is_json" : "hello!" }';

$arr = json_decode($jsonString, true);

echo $arr['this_is_json'] // "hello!";
```

What can be a little more conceptually confusing, is that PHP `json_decode` can return either an array of objects (rather than just an object), or an associative array.

Consider the following json string. This string represents a "collection" (square brackets) of json data structures (curly braces).

```
[
    {
        "name": "One"
    },
    {
        "name": "Two"
    }
]
```

If we assign this json to the variable `$string` hopefully this will illustrate the difference

```
$asObjects = json_decode($string);

$asAssociativeArray = json_decode($string, true);

foreach ($asObjects as $obj) {
    echo $obj->name;
}

foreach ($asAssociativeArray as $arr) {
    echo $arr['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are requesting an associative array (by passing True as the second parameter to the json_decode function) but trying to use it as an object.

Try `$json_array = json_decode($string,false);` . That will return objects

Also, as @MatRt mentions, you need to use $value instead of $key to reference the objects

Answer (score 3):

You need to retrieve values with array syntax:

```
$item['key']
```

as apposed to

```
$item->key
```

Comment: This is getting rid of the errors, but the variables are empty - when I use ` $store = $key['store'];` then try `print_r($store);` I get a blank screen

Comment: try foreach($json_array as $key)