# Get specific value from JSON response

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this response from Google Maps Distance Matrix API:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "334-350 Hicks St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "565-569 Vermont St, Brooklyn, NY 11207, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "6.5 mi",
                  "value" : 10410
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "34 mins",
                  "value" : 2045
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

How to exactly get the "6.5 mi" value?

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
$distance = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
```

Comment: Start with `var_dump($response_a)` Is it object or array?

Comment: Decoded it? Decoded it with the second parameter set to true?

Comment: check here : https://eval.in/591358

Comment: $jsonString = '{ "this_is_json" : "hello!" }';

$obj = json_decode($jsonString);

echo $obj->this_is_json // "hello!";

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578019/getting-json-data-with-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You received a JSON string from Google API. Decode it before using.

```
$arr = json_decode($response_a, true);
echo $arr['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
```