# How to fetch specific value from Json in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

i have this `Json` output and i want to get specific values from it, this is the `json` :

```
[
    [
        [
            "a:1:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:100;}",
            "a:1:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:200;}",
            "a:1:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:89;}"
        ],
        [
            "a:1:{s:3:\"USD\";d:100;}"
        ],
        [
            "a:2:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:300;s:3:\"USD\";d:250;}"
        ],
        [
            "a:1:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:30;}",
            "a:2:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:100;s:3:\"USD\";d:200;}"
        ],
        [
            "a:1:{s:3:\"USD\";d:200;}"
        ]
    ]
]
```

So i want to get the first `d` value only which are the numbers, for the moment i tried something like this:

```
$values = explode('-',$this->currency);
        return $values[0];
```

But its not working, i know i have to use a `foreach` to get the rest but dont know how to get the value for one.

**EDIT**
I did this code:

```
 $values = explode('-',$this->currency);

      foreach ($values as $val){
          $arr[] = unserialize($val);
      }
      return $arr;
```

And this is what i get

```
[
    [
        [
            {
                "ALL": 100
            },
            {
                "ALL": 200
            },
            {
                "ALL": 89
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "USD": 100
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "ALL": 300,
                "USD": 250
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "ALL": 30
            },
            {
                "ALL": 100,
                "USD": 200
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "USD": 200
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

So right now the output is correct but i need to get specific values for example on the first array we have 3 `ALL` values 100, 200, 89 i want to make a loop that gives me **separatly** 100, 200, 89 so i can find their total sum. The rest for the other numbers

**SECOND EDIT**

If i just make

```
$values = explode('-',$this->currency);
        
      return $values;
```

i get this result:

```
[
    [
        [
            "a:1:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:100;}",
            "a:1:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:200;}",
            "a:1:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:89;}"
        ],
        [
            "a:1:{s:3:\"USD\";d:100;}"
        ],
        [
            "a:2:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:300;s:3:\"USD\";d:250;}"
        ],
        [
            "a:1:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:30;}",
            "a:2:{s:3:\"ALL\";d:100;s:3:\"USD\";d:200;}"
        ],
        [
            "a:1:{s:3:\"USD\";d:200;}"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get specific value from JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897943/get-specific-value-from-json-response)

Comment: Use [json\_​decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode, then [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the value you want

Comment: @brombeer i can not use `json_decode` because its array and gives me error i did straight `unserialize` and i managed to get only the numbers as i want but how can i fetch only 1 number, this is the Json result i get now :

Comment: "_i can not use json_decode because its array_" You mentioned twice that this is JSON - and it is JSON - so you can use `json_decode` on it, I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: @brombeer well when i make json_decode($value) i get this error `Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given in file ` and the code i have is this:  `  $values = explode('-',$this->currency);  return json_decode($values);`

Comment: @laraCoder What is your expected output? Please add your desired output.

Comment: We have no idea (since you didn't post) what `$this->currency` is or what it contains and why you'd need to `explode()` it. Did you `dd($values)`?

Comment: @brombeer i added second edit

Comment: @brombeer as you can see i have the values formatted in that style so from all that i need to get only the currency and their values and find total sum for each small group example first group has 100,200,89 i need to find the sum to be 389

Comment: @laraCoder Please add sample response in json format what you want instead of writing in text. We can't understand your desired output.

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL the desired output is graphic in JS, what i need is for each of those sections example first section contains 3 values, `100` , `200`, `89` i need to find the sum of these 3 values which is `389` thats the desired output and put it in graphic Js

Comment: @laraCoder No, My mean that you need to add sample json array response. Like you have mentioned that `i get this result:` like that post the JSON array result.

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL i did post everything do you want to make a chat to see the whole code from the query of the database to here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Laravel, better to make use of the collection.
Suppose $contents is the array containing serialized values you can unserialize like as below.

```
$unserializedArray = collect($contents)
                        ->map(function($content){
                                /**
                                * Looping the inital array
                                */
                                return collect($content)
                                        ->map(function($data){
                                            /**
                                            * Looping the inner array
                                            */
                                            return collect($data)
                                                    ->map(function($seralized){
                                                        /**
                                                        * Unserializing the  
                                                        * seralized values 
                                                        */  
                                                        return unserialize($seralized);
                                                    });

                                        });
                            })->toArray();
```

You can write the same code mentioned above in short hand as below :

```
$unserializedArray = collect($content)
                        ->map(fn($data)=>collect($data)
                                ->map(fn($fArr)=>collect($fArr)
                                        ->map(fn($serialized)=>unserialize($serialized))))
                                            ->toArray();
```

Getting the value using the keys

```
$selectedKey = 'ALL';
$response    = collect($unserializedArray)
                 ->map(function($unserialized)use($selectedKey){
                     return collect($unserialized)
                              ->map(function($unserializeData)use($selectedKey){
                                 return collect($unserializeData)
                                            ->pluck($selectedKey);
                              })->collapse();
                 })->collapse()->filter()->values();
```

The $response is the collection of the $selectedKey so using it you can easily get sum or the array of values

```
 /**
  * Sum 
  */

  $sum = collect($response)->sum()

 /**
  * Array 
  */

  $responseArray = collect($response)->toArray()
```

You can also do all this as below as well :

```
        $selectedKey = 'ALL';
        $unserializedArray = collect($contents)
                                ->map(fn($content)=>
                                        collect($content)
                                            ->map(fn($serilizeArray) => 
                                                    collect($serilizeArray)
                                                        ->map(fn($serialized)=>unserialize($serialized))
                                                        ->pluck($selectedKey))
                                            ->collapse())
                                ->collapse();
        
        $sum   = collect($unserializedArray)->sum();
        
        $array = collect($unserializedArray)->toArray();
```